# how to submit a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I can't manage to submit the form after it's validated. the validation code works- the "alert()" text comes up, though the form is not submitted.

I've tried many options but none of them worked, please help.

Thank you!

HTML:

```
                    <label for="name"> Name: </label>
                    <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Full name" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="phone"> Phone Number: </label>
                    <input class="inputfield" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required placeholder="Phone Number" />
                    <br />

                    <!-- <label for="email"> E-mail: </label>
                    <input class="inputfield" type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email adress" />
                    <br /> -->

                    <label for="message"> Message: </label>
                    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message"> </textarea>
                    <br />

                    <div id="error"></div>   

                    <input class="submitform" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />

                </form>
            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#validation").submit(function(event){

        var errorMessage = "";

        event.preventDefault();


        if (!$.isNumeric($('#phone').val()) ) {

            errorMessage="Please enter a Valid Phone";

    }       

        if (errorMessage == "") {
            alert("good")
        } else {

          $("#error").html(errorMessage);

       }    


    });
```

Comment: Apart from moving the preventDefault, NEVER call a form element `submit`

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `event.preventDefault();` is preventing the submit. Try it like this:

```
$("#validation").submit(function(evt){
    var errorMessage = "";        

    if (!$.isNumeric($('#phone').val()) ) {
        errorMessage="Please enter a Valid Phone";
    }       

    if (errorMessage == "") {
        alert("good")
    } else {
      $("#error").html(errorMessage);
      evt.preventDefault();
   }    

});
```